# problems to get the full DATE info from Oracle DB (dd/mm/yyyy hh/mm/ss)

Tags: jpa, oracle11g

I have a column in a table in which we are storing date in DATETIME format. (DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SS) - Database Oracle 11g. 
Data Type of a column is DATE, and storing date in 01-01-2012 01:00 PM (i.e. jan 1, 2012) format.

entity

```
@NotNull
@Column(name = "dateColumnName")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date sampleDate;
```

I am fetching all data by passing date

```
SAMPLE_QUERY = "select * from TableA tab where tab.dateWithTime = :sampleDate order by tab.dateWithTime ASC "
```

> singleDate is "Tue Jan 24 00:00:00 IST 2012" , fasttime :
>   1327343400000

The problem is I am passing only date in the query, though Date through which records are being fetched is in DATE TIME format i.e 01-01-2012 01:00 PM.

How can i change my query so that it fetches all the records in ascending order of DateTime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch all times for that day, then change your query to be more like

```
SELECT ... WHERE dateField >= :lowerParam AND dateField < :upperParam
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle has no `DATE TIME` datatype. The `DATE` datatype contains both a date and a time component, down to the second. `TIMESTAMPS` get a bit more complicated.

If your `dateWithTime` column is indeed a DATE datatype, the `ORDER BY dateWithTime ASC` clause should order your results in ascending order.

You may not be displaying the time component of your date. You can convert a date to a string in that format with `TO_CHAR( dateWithTime, 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24/mm/ss' )` or whatever format you want.

Edit:

Oh, do you mean you want to find the cases where the date component of the `DATE` matches, but you don't care about the time component? That can be handled in the where clause with something like:

```
WHERE TRUNC( tab.dateWithTime ) = TRUNC( :sampledate )
```

TRUNC by default truncates a date to the beginning of the day.

Comment: Date column is storing date values with default time i,e 01-01-2012 01:00 PM, but i am passing only date with some default time. I want to fetch all records for that date in ASC. 01-01-2012 01:00 AM, 01-01-2012 03:00 AM, 01-01-2012 01:00 PM, 01-01-2012 02:00 PM <-- like this.

Comment: `DATE`s do not have a "default time". I'm not sure what you mean.